# Convert screen coordinate to UIView local point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've seen many examples of how you can convert local point of an UIView to screen coordinate. For example,

```
CGPoint subContentLocalPoint = subContent.frame.origin ;
CGPoint basePos = [subContent convertPoint:subContentLocalPoint toView:nil] ;
```

But how does one do the opposite? (i.e. convert screen coordinates to a UIView local point.)
For example,

Screen Coordinate - x:90 y:100
UIView content - x:0 y:0       // because this is where the UIView object is on the screen.

Comment: Change `toView:` to `fromView:`.

Comment: Also note that converting between view and screen coordinates is a two-step process. `convertPoint:toView:` and `convertPoint:fromView:` convert to and from window coordinates. You still have to convert these window coordinates to/from screen coordinates using `convertPoint:toWindow:` and `convertPoint:fromWindow:` on the correct `UIWindow`.

Comment: @fluidsonic The OP is asking for screen coordinates, not window. So passing `nil` and using one conversion is enough. And even if the conversion was to/from a `UIView` and a `UIWindow`, it can still be done in one step. Just pass the window as the to/from view.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep he's asking for screen coordinates. But the method he uses converts to window coordinates, which can be different. Window coordinates and screen coordinates are not the same.

Comment: @fluidsonic Right. I was thinking that a `nil` view meant screen coordinates, not window. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to get screen position from position of subContent.

`[subContent convertPoint:subContentLocalPoint fromView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];`

Answer (score 6):

Screen coordinates to specific view:

```
UIView* specificView = ...;
CGPoint pointInScreen = ...;
CGPoint pointInWindow = [specificView.window convertPoint:pointInScreen fromWindow:nil];
CGPoint pointInView = [specificView convertPoint:pointInWindow fromView:nil];
```